# Reliably align one element on screen edge after transforming

Tags: css, transform, css-transforms

So I'm trying to create a pure-css parallax effect. It's working pretty well, except that there's one parallaxed element I need plaster reliably against the right edge of the view space. After the translate and scale, this is proving... problematic. You can see my dumbed-down version [here](https://codepen.io/freer4/pen/RyyxOy), where the blue element should be against the right edge of the screen.

I've tried positioning and margin in several variations to no luck. Also tried some `translateX` but that's not a bulletproof solution either, as it appears to be based off of element size.

The very most important detail here is that the Blue block and Teal block will both have interactable content. The blue block is on top (z-index), so the teal block having a full-page-size container isn't an issue, but I can't do the same for the blue block, which unfortunately would otherwise fix the issue [like I have here](https://codepen.io/freer4/pen/jxxZBb).

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.box{
  perspective: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.main{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
.content{
  width:200px;
  background:cyan;
  margin:0 auto;
  height:1200px;
}
.stuck{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background:blue;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:20%;
  transform: translateZ(-4px) scale(5);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="main"><div class="content">Test<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />Test</div></div>
  <div class="stuck"></div>
</div>
```

How do I get that blue block to stay at the far right using just CSS?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 different problems that you need to solve.

The first one, correcting the transform, is solved in this snippet (view it at full page):

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.box{
  perspective: 1px;
  height: 95vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.main{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
.content{
  width:200px;
  background:cyan;
  margin:0 auto;
  height:95%;
}
.stuck{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background:lightblue;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:20%;
  transform: translateX(200vw) translateX(-200%) translateZ(-4px)  scale(5);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="main"><div class="content">Test<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />Test</div></div>
  <div class="stuck"></div>
</div>
```

There are 2 corrections applied

- translateX(-200%)   corrects the zoom. Since the zoom is 5, the box will be 400% wider, and we need to correct the half of this that is on the right side.
- translateX(200vw) corrects the perspective translation. since the perspective value is 1px, and the z movement is 4px, the right border that was at +50vw has moved to 4 * 50vw = 200vw.

The other problem is related to the scrollbar that appears when the content is higher than the body. Unfortunately, I don't know of a good solution for this problem, since the scrollbar width is not the same across browsers